# "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'" and "File "<string>", line 1 <br /> [/' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a calculator program in python but the code isn't working. When I run multiplication it just says

```py
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

and when I divide it says

```py
File "<string>", line 1
    [/'
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anybody know what might be happening here? I just can't figure it out.

```
import re
number = input("")
number_2 = 0
mathematical_operator = 0
numbers = 0
first_number = 0
second_number = 0
calculation = 0
if number.find("+") != -1:
    number_2 = number
    mathematical_operator = "+"
elif number.find("-") != -1:
    number_2 = number
    mathematical_operator = "-"
elif number.find(":" or "/") != -1:
    number_2 = re.sub(":", "/", number)
    mathematical_operator = "/"
elif number.find("x" or "*") != -1:
    number_2 = re.sub("x", "*", number)
    mathematical_operator = "*"
else:
    print("cancelled")
numbers = list(str(number_2.split(str(mathematical_operator))))
first_number = numbers[0]
second_number = numbers[1]
calculation = (eval(str(first_number) + mathematical_operator + str(second_number)))
print(calculation)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: You have many basic errors in your code. I suggest you to start with easier stuff and work your way up with the help of tutorials and documentations. For example, I'm pretty sure `number.find("x" or "*")` doesn't do what you think it does (it is basically equivalent to just `number.find("x")`).

Comment: Also, Python errors tend to be quite straightforward for the most part. This one says that you're trying to call `split` on an int which doesn't have that method. Did you maybe misplaced the parenthesis and meant `str(number2).split(str(mathematical_operator))`?

Comment: To echo the above, an exercise like this is worth taking slowly, and implementing one piece at a time, rather than trying to get everything working in one go. One word of warning, `3 * -1` won't do what you expect, because it will find the negative symbol and assume you want to do a subtraction.

Comment: Try to avoid using `eval()`! It can be dangerous to pair with user input.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `if s.find(x) != -1:` it is ***much*** more idiomatic and readable to simply do `if x in s:`